# Restructure git repo

Tags: git, github, package

I have a git repo structure like this-

```
main-repo
  -file1
  -file2
```

I want to convert it to something like-

```
main-repo
   -javascript
       -file1
       -file2
```

and then later on add another repo in another language like

```
main-repo
    -javascript
        -file1
        -file2
    -python
        -file1
        -file2
```

How to do this given that I already have several commits and tests are configure in travis.yml to run on push to master.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing is just to move the files and make a new commit.  This may or may not suffice.  On the one hand, of course you don't *yet* have history for the python files you're going to add, so this would make room for a complete history.  On the other hand, the individual files' early histories might not always show up the way you'd like (because git's handling of file moves, while not bad, is not perfect).

Another option is to rewrite the repo's history to look like it always had the desired directory structure.  You could do this with `git filter-branch`.  If the repo is reasonably small, then you could pass a `--tree-filter` argument with a script like

```
mkdir javascript
mv file1 file2 javascript
```

(or `mv *.js javascript`, or whatever makes sense).

This operation is notoriously slow, but for a relatively new repo with only "several" commits it should be reasonable.

Please see the git filter-branch docs for more details.  https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch

Comment: main-repo has release-tags associated with it as the code is packaged and published on npm. Will those tags remain intact. Also once I repackage the same code for new language like pypi in python will it be able to maintain separate release tag for it

Comment: @ShashiKumarRaja - `filter-branch` has a `tag-filter` argument which controls if/how tags are rewritten.  Typically `--tag-filter cat` does what is usually wanted (move the existing tags to the rewritten tree).  You can tag whatever you want going forward, but a tag always applies to *some object*, which usually is a commit - and a commit is a snapshot of all content.  For this (and many) reasons, it isn't advisable with git to store what are logically separate projects in a single repo.  So if these are separate enough to each need their own line of release tags, I'd consider using 2 repos.

Answer (score 3):

> I have a git repo structure like this- …
>   I want to convert it to something like- …

There's nothing wrong with moving files inside a repository. However, even though Git may autodetect file moves (as some would disappear and some others ones would appear, having the exact same content), there's a dedicated command to do so :

```
git mv <source> <destination>
```

The file will be automatically moved and this will show up in the `git status`'s report. You'll therefore need a commit to record this.

It's always a good idea to do so since one always want to avoid renaming/moving files in a git repository if not really needed. This because it breaks the continuum of history for these given files and make them difficult to trace back.

Each commit is supposed to be independent of the other ones, even if each one refers to the previous one (or ones when merged). They are basically a list of fully qualified file names each pointing at their respective contents, which enables you to easily compare (with `git diff`) any two commits wherever they lie in the graph.

This is really powerful but the drawback is that git is relying on file names to know what to compare. If there was only a few names changes between a commit and the next one, git will guess back which ones they actually are. But if you introduces both file changes and name renamings, or if you rename a file and create another one having the same content, it will be confused.

By using `git mv`, you give Git a chance to store every required information to help it doing this task. Also, in some other SCM that work differently, this could be mandatory.

> and then later on add another repo in another language like

Nothing special about this. Just add your extra stuff as you would do at the beginning (don't forget to commit, though) but be aware that Git cannot handle **empty directories**. So you'll need to add at least one file inside your "python" directory. It also means that once you've deleted the very last of the file in a given directory, the directory itself would also automatically disappear at next checkout. Don't be surprised about this.

This is due to the fact that, as stated before, Git only consider files (even if it remains able to deal with symbolic links and special files) and keep track of their respective places by maintaining a fully qualified file name (e.g. "/dirname/basename"). It therefore can't handle a branch that has no leaf at the end.

Also, if your "javascript" and "python" directories has nothing to do together (there not parts of given unique project), you'd better turn them into multiple, separate git repositories. Keep in mind that you can always init a new repository with `git init` even if there's already some stuff in it.

Finally, when you've reached the point where you want to make a repository inside a bigger one, for example to publicly share the little one while keeping some additional information about it, or when working on a large project in which one of its libraries is a project on its own, you'll want to check `git submodule` out, but not today. :)